# Fade in background color using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to take a div and have the background fade to white on mouseenter and fade back out to black on mouseout. Any ideas on how to do this in jQuery?

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with JQuery .hover()

```
  $("div" ).hover(
  function() {
     $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 'slow');
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#000"},'slow');
  });
```

with JQuery .mouseover()

```
$("div")
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 'slow');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#000"},'slow');
  });
```

**Note** you have to use jquery-color (for animating colors). https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either [jQuery UI libarary](http://jqueryui.com/) or [jQuery Colors](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) to enable animation of colors

```
$('div').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    })
}, function () {
     $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kw2bB/)

Answer (score 0):

OP requested jQuery. For those trying to free-hand without jQuery:

```
<div id="x" style="background-color:rgb(255,255,105)">hello world</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unBlue=100;
    var gEvent=setInterval("toWhite();", 100);
    function toWhite(){
        if(unBlue<255) document.getElementById("x").style.backgroundColor="rgb(255,255,"+unBlue+")";
        else clearInterval(gEvent);
        unBlue+=10;
    }
</script>
```