# jQuery: How can I transition to another background color through console?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the fade in a different background-color of my  tag through console. I am using the command `$('body').animate({backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 'slow');` that I got [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441806/fade-in-background-color-using-jquery) but all it does it returns the jQuery object which represents body. I do have jQuery included.

How can I transition to another background color through console?
[image]

Comment: IMO, you would have better to toggle a class and use CSS transition

Answer (score 3):

By default you can't animate background with jQuery:

From animate jquery doc :

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

But you can use a plugin :

eg: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 0):

if you can do without animate. try this :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor='#000';
```