# Color changing while moving Up/Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with that JS..

-Have a `divs` and this is changing automatic in row where they are changing randomly...

- I need to change the color to green for the the `div` which is moving up..
- And for `div` which is moving down to change for red..

I tried to do that but i did just that while moving up and down change same color..

So should i did a `class` or `id` to check the divs position and in JS set something like :

... `check` the position of div
... `if` moving up like change the position to lower value change 'green'
... `else` change to lower value like from '2' to '5' change for 'red'

Here is the sample how its work now: [CLICK HERE FOR SAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbyVxP)

Here is the main file for JS: [MAIN JS FILE for **MixItUp**](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/2.1.8/jquery.mixitup.js)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mixit = $('#Container').mixItUp({
    load: {
      sort: 'random'
    },
    layout: {
      containerClass: 'list',
      display: 'block'
    }
  });
  
  function loop() {
    mixit.mixItUp('sort', 'random');
  };    
  
  var looper = setInterval(loop, 20000);
});
```

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #68b8c4;
}

.mix.category-1 {
  height: 50px;
}

#Container .mix {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-color: white;
}

.container{
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.1px;
  margin-left: 35%;
  
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .mix,
.container .gap{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}

.container .mix{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}

.container .mix:after{
  content: attr(data-myorder);
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 4% 6%;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container .mix:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/latest/jquery.mixitup.min.js?v=2.1.9"></script>
<div id="Container" class="container">
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="1"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="2"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="3"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="4"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="5"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="6"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="7"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mixit = $('#Container').mixItUp({
    load: {
      sort: 'random'
    },
    layout: {
      containerClass: 'list',
      display: 'block'
    }
  });

  function loop() {
    var arr = [];
    i = 0;
    $('.mix').each(function(){
      arr[i++] = $(this).data('myorder');
    });
    mixit.mixItUp('sort', 'random');

    mixit.on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
      var arr2 = [];
    i2 = 0;
    $('.mix').each(function(){
      arr2[i2++] = $(this).data('myorder');
    });
    for(i=0; i<i2; i++){
      for(j=0; j<i2; j++){
        if(arr[i]==arr2[j]){
          if(i<j){
            $('.mix').eq(j).css("background-color", "red");
          }
          if(i>j){
            $('.mix').eq(j).css("background-color", "green");
          }
        }
      }
    }
    });
  };

  var looper = setInterval(loop, 3000);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And if i want to set a fadeOut to red color because it fade out whole row in but thanks a lot u're my hero it works perfectly

Comment: Glad that it helped you. For fading effect, you can try this: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441806/fade-in-background-color-using-jquery)

Comment: I tried this .animate({backgroundColor: "#green"}, 'slow') and its not work... the color doesnt appear in...